# How to merge two methods with the same implementation but different parameter types

Tags: java

The operations in my two methods are the same, but the input parameter types are different, so how can I optimize these two methods, it seems that they are not so repetitive?
Because their operations are the same, but the parameter types are different, what should I do to make this code more elegant?

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseStudent baseStudent = new BaseStudent();
        baseStudent.setName("base");
        NbdStudent nbdStudent = new NbdStudent();
        nbdStudent.setName("nbd");
        updateName(baseStudent);
        updateName(nbdStudent);
    }

    private static void updateName(BaseStudent student) {
        student.setName("update base");
    }

    private static void updateName(NbdStudent student) {
        student.setName("update base");
    }

}
```

Comment: Do the classes e.g. have a common parent, which they inherit from?

Comment: You haven’t shown the definition of your types. Purely based on the name I’d assume that `NbdStudent` inherits from `BaseStudent`, correct?

Comment: Create an abstract class called Student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your students class extend from the same (abstract) base class or implement the same interface.

#### Using classes

Since the two classes are both students you can define a common parent (lets say `BaseStudent` is the common parent)

```
/* BaseStudent.java */
// abstract is optional, depends on if you want
// to make the class instantiable or having some
// methods that are not implemented
abstract class BaseStudent {
  public String name;
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}

/* NbdStudent.java */
class NbdStudent extends BaseStudent { }


/* main file */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseStudent baseStudent = new BaseStudent();
        baseStudent.setName("base");
        NbdStudent nbdStudent = new NbdStudent();
        nbdStudent.setName("nbd");
        updateName(baseStudent);
        updateName(nbdStudent);
    }

    private static void updateName(BaseStudent student) {
        student.setName("update base");
    }
}
```

#### Using interfaces

In a more broad way you can abstract your classes to have a common behaviour but a different implementation

```
/* Named.java */
interface Named {
  public void setName(String name);
}

/* BaseStudent.java */
class BaseStudent implements Named {
  public String name;
  public void setName(String name) {
    // different implementation simple example
    if (name == null) { name = "BaseStudent with no name"; }
    this.name = name;
  }
}

/* NbdStudent.java */
class NbdStudent implements Named {
  public String name;
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}

/* main file */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseStudent baseStudent = new BaseStudent();
        baseStudent.setName("base");
        NbdStudent nbdStudent = new NbdStudent();
        nbdStudent.setName("nbd");
        updateName(baseStudent);
        updateName(nbdStudent);
    }

    private static void updateName(Named student) {
        student.setName("update base");
    }
}
```

Comment: My BaseStudent and NbdStudent are inherited from other classes, and can no longer extract public classes to inherit

Comment: If you can manage to implement interfaces on your classes you are still ok with the implementation, since the "common parent" is the interface itself